# A question about notation and tests.

Tags: functions

I'm by no means a mathematician (and therefore not even sure if this question is suitable for here), but I'm studying mathematical modelling of biological systems and I've come up against this expression in the context of testing for a difference in component score (α vs β, derived from matrices A and B):

[image]

I'd love to be able to look up more about this and learn it for myself but sadly this is proving unrealistic. Please could someone explain the "double modulus"(?) notations surrounding α and β, and how to interpret this kind of expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lVert a\rVert_2$ is what we call the 2-norm of $a$.If $a$ is just the number, then it is the same as $|a|$, but if $a$ is a vector, i.e. $a=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$, then

$$\lVert a\rVert_2=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+\ldots +a_n^2}$$

Norms are how we measure distances and we generally use the notation $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ for them. The little $2$ is there because there are many different norms (different ways to define 'distance') and the $2$ tells us which one we are looking at. In this case, it is the standard norm that you probably saw at some point in high school when you were looking at distances in a plane or in space.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful. I know this is probably super elementary but do you have any further advice on how to interpret this test taking into account the fact that I've never seen an expression in the form of x = [...] > 0 ?

Comment: $x= y >0$ just means that x is equal to $y$ (probably by definition in this case) and that $y$ and $x$ are both strictly larger than 0.
I don't know enough about the background to be able to talk about the interpretation of the test fully. What is roughly happening is that $\frac{\lVert \alpha_j\rVert}{\sqrt{|A|}}$ seems to be some interesting quantity and it is said that the difference between this quantity for $\alpha_j$ and $A$ is strictly larger than the same quantity for $\beta_j$ and $B$. $\Delta_j$ is then defined as that difference.

Comment: Thank you so much- I'll finally be able to code this algorithm.